# Can't install some software due to "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect"

Tags: windows-10, installation, visual-c++

So I can't install [Samsung Kies 1 and SmartSwitch](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) as I get this error message when running the installer:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
>   configuration is incorrect

Full, untranslated message

> Diese Anwendung konnte nicht gestartet werden, da die
>   Side-by-Side-Konfiguration ungültig ist. Weitere informationen finden
>   sie im Anwendungsereignisprotokoll. Weitere Details können auch mit
>   dem Befehlszeilentool sxstrace.exe angezeigt werden.

I'm running a freshly-installed UEFI Windows 10 64Bit machine.

In the event log I see these errors (event id 33):

> Activation context generation failed for "C:..\Smart_Switch_pc_setup.exe". Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

SxsTrace doesn't give me more info. All other installers (except these 2) that I have run by now have been running just fine.

Some things I already tried:

- Restart
- Running `sfc /scannow`
- Deinstalling all Visual C++ Redistributables for 64Bit (2005-2015), restarting, reinstalling them, restarting again
- Just installing Visual C++ Redistributable 2008 64Bit
- Installing Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package ATL Security
- Running the installer as admin
- The registry changes detailed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2525435/prevent-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its-side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect...-error-starting-access) (I only have 1 version nr which also is properly set)
- Cleaning and reinstalling .NET Framework
- Checking for Windows updates

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Microsoft.**VC90.DebugCRT**,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="**9.0.21022.8**"

This message means the tool was compiled in Debug mode in Visual Studio 2008, so you need the VC++ 2008 **Debug** Runtime.

But this runtime is not allowed to be shared/redist via installer. So ask Samsung Support to release a new version of the software that is compiled in Release mode.

*// Edit*,

if it is MFC, install the [32Bit Visual C++ 2008 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582), because win32 = x86.

Comment: Oh I made a mistake - it wasn't **.DebugCRT** but **.MFC**. Sorry and thanks anyways...

Comment: ok, I added the new link. you need the 32Bit DLL, not 64bit.

Comment: This fixed it - thank you! I thought I tried some 32Bit versions but apparently not the right (2008) one...